# How to make the object wait a little before it disappears?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a beginner in coding and I made when the player pass a object to disappear but in my case the object must wait a little before it disappears. I'm showing my code here below, if you can give me ideas how to modify the code. Thank you

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)

if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Circle"))
 
Destroy(other.gameObject);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [the Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) you can see that `Destroy` has an optional second parameter to pass a delay before the destruction actually happens.

So in your case e.g. `Destroy(other.gameObject, 1f);` would destroy it 1 second later.

Answer (score 1):

You can Use Coroutine its pretty Simple Here is an Exaple using the code you provided

```
IEnumerator wait()
{
yield return new WaitForSeconds(sec);
Destroy(other.gameObject);
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)

if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Circle"))
 StartCorutine(waiter);
```